# Global class that can used throughout all other classes

Tags: cocoa-touch, design-patterns

I have implemented iAds into my app successfully in one particular view controller, and I want to put them in many of my other view controllers. It seems redundant to write the same iAd code over and over each again for each view controller. I want to be able to put all this code for iAds in one class and just call it whenever I need it. So I have heard of things called helper classes and class methods(+) but I am not sure if this what I need. Can anyone lead me in the right direction? An example would be helpful.

**Edit**

I created a singleton class without a view controller and I think thats right. Anyways in the iAd implementation, there are many lines of code that include adding a subview such as

```
[self.view addSubview:adView];
```

The singleton is telling me that it does not recognize "view". So when I am calling the singleton from my other view controllers, do I need to pass the view to the singleton? Thank you

Comment: I've edited out your disclaimer; questions should really just contain technical content. The best way to avoid taking flak for asking what you think may be a too-basic question is not to apologize, but to do some research and ask about the results. For example, have you searched on SO for key terms from your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcocoa%5D+global+class

Comment: @W'rkncacnter Okay makes sense thank you. Except what you have sent me to refers mainly to global variables which I am not sure is what I am looking for? I want to be able to access everything

Comment: Well, I didn't say that was the exact right search -- it was just a suggestion. Here's a hint, though: look for information on "singletons". In fact, I am surprised you don't already have five answers suggesting using a singleton.

Comment: @W'rkncacnter Singleton? Never heard of those. I will look into it. Thank you. If you want to leave your comment as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: If you get 5 answers suggesting a singleton, you'll get at least a dozen saying singletons are evil and you should use dependency injection.

Comment: @DonRoby Thanks for the reply. Which one do you recommend and can you briefly explain dependency injection? Thanks

Comment: @W'rkncacnter You seem to have a good understanding of singletons and I am trying to implement them and was wondering if you could help me? I have edited my question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new class, the iAd singleton, does indeed not have a view; thus you cannot access one from there.

I would suggest that, rather than passing the view controller's view to the iAd class, you have your VCs request the ad. Something like this:

```
// SomeViewController
// Maybe this is viewDidLoad? It's wherever you are ready to 
// incorporate the ad into your view.
- (void) arrangeViewIncludingAds
{
    // Do other setup

    UIView * adView [[iAdSingleton sharedIAd] adWithParameters:infoToSelectAnAppropriateAdForThisVC];
    [self.view addSubview:adView];

    // Continue setup
}
```

I'm not sure if you want to change the ads for each VC or not; I just added that as an idea.

Answer (score 1):

what is it you are trying to share? from the description, you sound like you are most interested in reusing an implementation (as opposed to various global data/state). you can use multiple instances of a class for this purpose.

of course, you may want to focus this class' interface such that it interacts well with the views and controllers you must use it with (in a generic manner -- special cases should stay in the appropriate controller).

Comment: This is an excellent point. I just suggested "singleton" to give Alex a starting point.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I would accept but @W'rkncacnter has provided me feedback from the beginning of the post but I appreciate your input